# Group homomorphism in category theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Too often i come across the statement a functor between two groups as categories is the homomorphism between the corresponding groups. This may be trivial, but has anybody proved is necessary and sufficient condition in detail showing how the object part and arrow part of the finctor can be fixed to prove.
Thanks for help

Comment: What have you tried? If a group as a category has a single object, what do you think the object function of the functor is going to be?  What does the preservation of composition mean in terms of the group structures? etc

Comment: On the other hand, $Grp$ can be taken simply to be: $Obj(Grp)$: sets with a corresponding group structure; $Morph(Grp)$:group homomorphisms. This has the advantage that one can then obtain a "free" object (group) given by the left adjoint to the forgetful functor.

Comment: When you are reading a math text and you come across such a statement, you are expected to stop reading and pick up a pencil and find the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it *is* quite trivial: both groups consist of a single object, so the functor can only map the first object to the second. For two arrows $g,h$ in the first group, and a functor $f$ to the second group, functoriality means that $f(gh) = f(g)f(h)$. But this is precisely the definition of a group homomorphism.

Comment: Suppose we have a group homomorphism f between gr A and grB. We now have to define a functor between to corresponding categories A* and B* which have single object

Comment: @ManojKumarMukherjee Yes. This functor maps each arrow (element of the first group) to its image under the homomorphism.